# Catch an inherited event before allowing it to bubble up

Tags: node.js, sockets, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I am currently working on a class that implements a TCP/IP encapsulated protocol.  I am extending the NodeJS [`Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) class. My issue is that I need to stop the parent events from bubbling up and emit appropriate events for my needs.

Here is an illustration of what I want though I am unsure as to how to actually implement it.

```
const { Socket } = require("net");

class Sample extends Socket {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    // How do I catch and prevent the parent event from bubbling 
    super.on('data', data => {
        functionsToStopBubbling();

        if(data.toString() === "foo") {
            this.emit('event1', 1);
        } else {
            this.emit('event2', 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to do this (preferably the ES2015 method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're speaking of is not bubbling.  It's not like events in the browser DOM that bubble up the hierarchy.  The Socket object is an `eventEmitter`.  When both you and someone else are registered for the `data` event, there is no way (short of hacking the eventEmitter data structures) for you to get that event, but not the other people who are registered for it.  Event emitters just don't work that way.

The only way I know of to prevent them from getting it is to override their listening to that event and change their listener to listen to some other event which you can trigger when you want to and then they won't ever see the `data` events.

But, if the client of your socket is aware that it's a special type of socket, then **you should just document how they should use your special type of socket** so they don't listen to the `data` event in the first place.  Tell them which events they should listen to.

Here's how you could intercept their registering for the `data` event:

```
class Sample extends Socket {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // now listen for the data event
        super.on('data', function(data) {
           // do something with incoming data
        });
    }
    addListener(name, fn) {
       // intercept registering for data event
       if (name === 'data') {
           // change their listener to "myData" so I can trigger
           // when I want to and they won't get normal data events
           return super.addListener("myData", fn);
       } else {
           // let it go through to base class
           return super.addListener(name, fn);
       }
    }
    on(name, fn) {
        return this.addListener(name, fn);
    }
}
```

Note, you will have to use `super.on(...)` or `super.addListener(...)` yourself if you want to listen to the `data` event yourself.

---

Or, if you can just tell your client to use different events:

```
class Sample extends Socket {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // now listen for the data event
        this.on('data', function(data) {
           // do something with incoming data
           // and then emit some other events
           this.emit(...);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was beginning to suspect this, perhaps stopping the propagation of the event is not that important. That said, what is important is to add a listener for the `Socket.on('data', data => console.log(data))` event within the class and emit new events that are relevant to my new child class.  Does this make sense? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: @canaanseaton - Yeah, that makes sense.  Just document for your client that they should listen to the new events, not to the `data` event.

Comment: will do, and i can catch the Parent events by simply making a class method like `on('data', ...)`?

Comment: @canaanseaton - You don't make a method to just listen to events.  You just put `this.on('data', fn)` in one of your existing methods.

Comment: hmm, interesting.  Would you mind putting some sample code on how to do this in your response? thanks!

Comment: @canaanseaton - Example added.